# 「来たるべきバカのために」 in a book title

Tags: interpretation

The title of [this book](https://www.amazon.co.jp/%E5%8B%89%E5%BC%B7%E3%81%AE%E5%93%B2%E5%AD%A6-%E6%9D%A5%E3%81%9F%E3%82%8B%E3%81%B9%E3%81%8D%E3%83%90%E3%82%AB%E3%81%AE%E3%81%9F%E3%82%81%E3%81%AB-%E5%8D%83%E8%91%89-%E9%9B%85%E4%B9%9F/dp/4163905367) is 「勉強の哲学 来たるべきバカのために」.

What's the intended meaning of 来たるべきバカのために? I would venture "For the fool who is to come" (i.e. 'the fool who will be with us in the future'), but why?

Comment: There are some reviews under the link you posted which are discussing the question you posed, including the book description.

Comment: A review about this book says 「来たるべきバカ」means 「ノリを良くもできる人」.

Comment: I guess it's related to: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/54583/what-is-a-similar-suffix-to-itis-in-japanese